# Отдых в Саках или отдых в городе Саки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, топонимика

Нужен комментарий практикующего филолога по корректности написания словосочетания: *отдых в Саках* или *отдых в городе Саки.*
Дело в том, что, согласно *Грамоте.ру*, равноправными признаются оба варианта: мн. ч. и ед. ч. мужского рода (неизменяемое), т. е. можно говорить *бывал в Саках* и *бывал в Саки*.
Но географические названия в сочетании с родовым словом *город* не склоняются. Ссылка на ту же *Грамоту.ру*. Отсюда получается, что правильно так: *отдых в городе Саки.*
Или все же корректно: *отдых в Саках*?

[Саки](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Можно ссылку на то место, где "согласно грамоте.ру"?

Answer (score 1):

Процитирую отрывок из сборника "Орфография собственных имён" (Наука, 1965 г.).

> Существует расхождение между употреблением подобных названий типа
> pluralia tantum в центре и на местах. В центре они часто остаются без склонения, а если и
> склоняются, то не всегда так, как это принято на местах. Так,
> например, в Евпаторийском районе принято склонять: *Саки — в Саках*,
> *Мойнаки — из Мойнак*. В центре в употреблении их чувствуется неловкость и их предпочитают оставлять несклоняемыми: Он был в Саки,
> лечился в Мойнаки. Тогда оба названия становятся неопределенного рода
> и могут согласовываться с прилагательными и глаголами любого рода.
> Аналогичное положение наблюдается с названием **Сочи**.

Далее приводятся примеры из литературы с ед. и мн. числом для Сочи. Это меня особо удивило. Я подумал было, что язык не повернётся сказать "знал бы прикуп — жил бы в Сочах", но как же я был удивлён, попытавшись нагуглить эту фразу.

С тех пор прошло более 50 лет — срок немалый для развития языка. Сегодня мы видим, что большее распространение получило мн. число для Саков и ед. — для Сочи. Но такие процессы всегда инертны. Например, современный словарь собственных имен Ф.Л. Агеенко рекомендует **Саков** для родительного падежа, но и в гугло-книгах и в общем гугле варианты **Саки** и **Сак** для Р.п. всё ещё встречаются чаще.

Сошлюсь для порядка на общее правило, которое гласит, что всё дело только в том, как воспринимается название носителями языка.

> 1.6. Топонимы, оканчивающиеся на гласные -и, -ы и не воспринимающиеся в русском языке как формы мн. числа, даются в несклоняемой форме,
> например: Бурли, нескл. (с., Казахстан); Карши, нескл. (с.,
> Туркмения); Исмаиллы, нескл., (гор., Азербайджан); Мары, нескл. (гор.,
> Туркмения); Джусалы, нескл. (пгт, Казахстан).

Answer (score 0):

Всё что нашел на грамоте - http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=222763
Но это всего лишь "Справка", источник по нынешним временам малоавторитетный.
Словари (на той же грамоте) несклоняемый вариант не поддерживают.

> т.е. даже можно употреблять: бывал в Саках и бывал в Саки.

Второй вариант весьма сомнителен. На совести "Справки".

> Отсюда получается, что правильно: отдых в городе Саки. Или все же корректно: отдых в Саках?

Оба варианта корректны. Вы немного подзапутались. Несклоняемый вариант, на допустимости которого настаивает "Cправка", касается только формы "отдых в Саки" - вот это-то и сомнительно. А у вас два возможных варианта - с родовым словом и без.

Answer (score -1):

Ориентироваться нужно по Грамоте.ру. То есть корректно в употреблении и то и то.

Заменим на название известного города для аналогии, чтобы понять разницу. Есть два корректных варианта:
1) *отдых в городе Москве*; || Звучит слишком официально.
2) *отдых в Москве*. || Звучит дружелюбно. В отдыхе где-то важно дружелюбие.

Если город где-то рядом и о нём знают люди (для которых это написано), то лучше — *отдых в Саках*; а если город далёкий и о нём никто не знает, то, наверно, лучше — *отдых в городе Саки* (это также даёт представление о том, что это некий город, а не что-либо другое).

Comment: *В городе Москва* в любом случае неправильно.

Comment: Получается, надо: *в городе Москве*. Да, так не говорят, но грамматически это правильно.

Comment: Как раз так и говорят.))

Comment: Да ладно) Как-то оно не очень, избыточно звучит, так как все знают, что Москва — это город.

Comment: А-а, ты про само сочетание с родовым словом. С этим-то я согласен: в большинстве случаев лучше говорить просто *в Москве.*